# IIS gives 400 Bad Request for some links

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity for generating activation urls in format

```
https://example.com/activate/token
```

Where token is generated by Asp Identity and looks like this

```
Cl%2bsBAAAA2qxQHU9GHUuBNXILrSEDWgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAADds1gNf52iBX54Z6V%2bY5ZJEZmCmhgPetK2mEuu5pEiLwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADjqFZ3Qrk6o22AHQDtoo%2bUNO4NZZ9RubxnuFBPTwyX/3AAAAATHRJIHkbDX2PmNxDYV0e2P5uAohDpMlpaP1C/KjV1mz5z06X7YaehipzlgLa4IxcAT8AQK%2bW4Qxq4Y3No0kaVNQRpSIzdB6cv%2bjn47IY5hburRgSPbZ6L7xvmWoreBZCCBn4SHMxbcdfAKEnkDELpQAAAAIwoV4hLdqQyV5g6WAQM/kiO3/FKyauZKsWBI/tA/M7uq7CDiQRdZxqdO0SUO9xW851luaKDP6bi/daxEhAemzk%3d
```

Problem is sometimes ~1 in 10 times I get generic 400 error

```
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

Example bad link

```
http://example.org/activate/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl%2bsBAAAA2qxQHU9GHUuBNXILrSEDWgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACrbeGsadAFQETqBTsIuxf%2bJZqK0JOQvGC6M250gHsTEQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACo6YtEGtjrvRO74X2G2VAQ1pAlBWksjnLo0zGxwrVrSXAAAAA%2bFfiwK3sL%2bbzK9wbM0r7Hoy4tueNmh4CNLD%2b2HeP7IldrAq40XbeLW0zlZo3CC2qWBfaGb5Z4HjziVYVT2Fvpg6dtm9UAmI4h5BPjzIBcJo8ZpiE4Z%2bQedRpAijhMHfsV2IDNptzCREWe3Wefi9aoQAAAAPzg9TNEhsqf76Qir%2bIyMxuuPsQkVykZVYFJ9/aI3EAAWK2de2VTUsXQBgdS4OGSI4AaAUEN%2b0Akdohw3Jd8zFo%3d
```

I think the problem is somewhere in IIS request is not hitting my application anywhere and, that's very strange, same error is showing on other websites like microsoft.com.

Eg.this makes 400 error

```
https://microsoft.com/en-us/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl%2bsBAAAA2qxQHU9GHUuBNXILrSEDWgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACrbeGsadAFQETqBTsIuxf%2bJZqK0JOQvGC6M250gHsTEQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAACo6YtEGtjrvRO74X2G2VAQ1pAlBWksjnLo0zGxwrVrSXAAAAA%2bFfiwK3sL%2bbzK9wbM0r7Hoy4tueNmh4CNLD%2b2HeP7IldrAq40XbeLW0zlZo3CC2qWBfaGb5Z4HjziVYVT2Fvpg6dtm9UAmI4h5Bhsqf76Qir%2bIyMxuuPsQkVykZVYFJ9/aI3EAAWK2de2VTUsXQBgdS4OGSI4AaAUEN%2b0Akdohw3Jd8zFo%3d
```

but this 404 error

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl%2bsBAAAA2qxQHU9GHUuBNXILrSEDWgAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAbr0DBVHVcY2tO3Rvvk15d5%2bIuV3usPJmD2FTF15vpbwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAXddKnTogsgCGRRhIzbXbk14fsjcLJ5L0q5C/dRfsYlHAAAAAlAw9iARuxhShyGfzE6ZF193fX7zvxLnOfjgh74G5oLc5RPIVdQ7O8sJdj5H0BnysPxrCMk965izZRqjBKGZFNl6smYdmaGy5aPqxI1kTez%2bhHQH1GMW3GUmF%2bRoYdRqcmJLErgcb4sgMa7UGA16X1QAAAAJTk6s6OzBuA2B8whkUdwQnrCS2xgf7QR%2blA%2bm7UqUdXuhQfiFkL/oCINhyrJt%2bWJsjxvGhOcsW15DtzyqKvlWY%3d
```

It looks like length sometimes have meaning but not really?
Similar question but caused by known characters - [%09 in a URL causes IIS (HTTP.SYS?) to return HTTP 400 immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534080/09-in-a-url-causes-iis-http-sys-to-return-http-400-immediately)

PS. Url in format `http://example.com/activate?token=token` work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is caused by the max length for Url segment (UrlSegmentMaxLength).

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows